# Unable to cast usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm getting an error that appears at seemingly random occations.

> Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.controls_ucscalevalue_ascx' to type
>   'Controls_ucScalevalue'.

what makes it weird is that it sometimes occur, and then dissappears with no real change in the code.

we're 2 people working on this project, while the error appear on one machine, the other is able to run it error free. According to github we're both completely synced up.

the line that triggers the code is this one

```
Controls_ucScalevalue value = (Controls_ucScalevalue)Page.LoadControl("Controls/ucScalevalue.ascx");
```

it works 90% of the time, but the last 10% we're somewhat stuck and can't figure out how to get rid of this error message.

Comment: Looks like a race condition. Where do you call the Page.LoadControl() from? An event handler before Page_Load()?

Comment: Don't you need to replace "Controls/ucScalevalue.ascx" with "~/Controls/ucScalevalue.ascx"??

Comment: It started working again, but i'll try the ~ next time it fails.

the loadcontrol is called in a method inside another usercontrol, which, for now, only appears on one page.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of microsoft. If you edit the user control sometimes the error dissapear, if you edit other control the error appears again. It occurs in proyects in asp.net 2.0. In MSN you can read about the error and download the fix. Here: [msdn fix loadcontrol](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB915782)